# EntityGraph default type(or explicitly configured as fetch) does not work

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My code is

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:5.6.11.Final"
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'
hibernate {
    enhance {
        enableLazyInitialization= true
    }
}
```

```
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long> {

  @EntityGraph("Question.test")
  @Query("from Question q where q.id = :id")
  Question testFindOne(Long id);
}
```

```
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Question.test",
    attributeNodes = {
      @NamedAttributeNode(value = "tags"),
      @NamedAttributeNode(value = "createdUserInfo")
    })
public class Question extends AuditEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @ToString.Exclude
  @NotEmpty
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "标签列表", notes = "创建修改问题时只需要传id即可")
  private Set<Tag> tags;

  @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
  @JsonIgnore
  private boolean awarded = false;
  //other field...
}
```

```
public class AuditEntity {

  @CreatedBy
  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "createdUser")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "ip", column = @Column(name = "createdIp", length = 32))
  })
  @JsonIgnore
  @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
  private Auditor createdUser;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "createdUser",
      referencedColumnName = "id",
      updatable = false,
      insertable = false)
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
  private User createdUserInfo;
}
```

```
public class User implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3692366870616346904L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  @ToString.Exclude
  private Point point;

}
```

And the testFindOne method is called with below sqls

```
select
        question0_.id as id1_38_0_,
        tag2_.id as id1_65_1_,
        user3_.id as id1_71_2_,
        question0_.createdTime as createdt2_38_0_,
        question0_.createdUser as createdu3_38_0_,
        question0_.createdIp as createdi4_38_0_,
        question0_.modifiedTime as modified5_38_0_,
        question0_.modifiedUser as modified6_38_0_,
        question0_.modifiedIp as modified7_38_0_,
        question0_.awarded as awarded8_38_0_,
        question0_.closed as closed9_38_0_,
        question0_.extraId as extraid16_38_0_,
        question0_.publishTime as publish11_38_0_,
        question0_.reward as reward12_38_0_,
        question0_.status as status13_38_0_,
        question0_.summary as summary14_38_0_,
        question0_.title as title15_38_0_,
        tag2_.circleId as circleid5_65_1_,
        tag2_.createdTime as createdt2_65_1_,
        tag2_.modifiedTime as modified3_65_1_,
        tag2_.name as name4_65_1_,
        tags1_.Question_id as question1_47_0__,
        tags1_.tags_id as tags_id2_47_0__,
        user3_.account as account2_71_2_,
        user3_.avatarPath as avatarpa3_71_2_,
        user3_.company as company4_71_2_,
        user3_.nickname as nickname5_71_2_,
        user3_.school as school6_71_2_,
        user3_.title as title7_71_2_,
        user3_.userName as username8_71_2_ 
    from
        question question0_ 
    left outer join
        question_tags tags1_ 
            on question0_.id=tags1_.Question_id 
    left outer join
        tag tag2_ 
            on tags1_.tags_id=tag2_.id 
    left outer join
        user user3_ 
            on question0_.createdUser=user3_.id 
    where
        question0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        point0_.userId as userid1_34_0_,
        point0_.dailyAwardPoint as dailyawa2_34_0_,
        point0_.dailyClock as dailyclo3_34_0_,
        point0_.modifiedTime as modified4_34_0_,
        point0_.point as point5_34_0_,
        point0_.versionId as versioni6_34_0_ 
    from
        point point0_ 
    where
        point0_.userId=?
```

According `EntityGraphType.fetch` doc ，Properties that are not specified in `EntityGraph` will be regarded as lazy properties and will not load.

If I remove add the lazy fetch to the point properties，it appears pretty normal. The properties that not specified in EntityGraph will not appears in sql.
Seems that the EntityGraphType strategy is not useful for nested entity.

```
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  @ToString.Exclude
  private Point point;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hint, not a requirement. JPA providers may ignore this. Having said that, Hibernate 6 fixed a lot of bugs in that area, but I think you are better off with a DTO model and this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Question.class)
public interface QuestionDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    Set<TagDto> getTags();
    UserDto getCreatedUserInfo();

    @EntityView(Tag.class)
    interface TagDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }

    @EntityView(User.class)
    interface UserDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`QuestionDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, QuestionDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<QuestionDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!